# Apache Spark: Disable Spark Web UI in Spark Standalone mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running Apache Spark 2.1.1 in Standalone Mode with client deploy mode.
**I want to disable Spark web UI for master and all workers**.

Refered to: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-ui and 
Used following conf in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.ui.showConsoleProgress=false
spark.ui.enabled=false
spark.ui.killEnabled=false
```

Yet I could still see web UI at default port 8080 (for Spark Master and 8081 for Spark Worker).
I have the same configuration in all the worker nodes.

Comment: `spark.ui.*` are for the web UI of a Spark application not a Spark Standalone cluster. These are two different things (and is somewhat a coincidence that these two use Spark in their names and web UI to refer to...well...web UI). How do you want to manage a Spark Standalone cluster if you disabled the web UI?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski My spark cluster is small (only 2-3 nodes) and hence manging it will not be an issue for me. But for security reasons, I need to make sure that No web components are exposed (like Spark web UI). Is there any way to turn it off?

Comment: Hello. Did you ever find a solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that their is no way to disable Spark Master UI.

However, you can change the port it is running on with /spark-master.sh -p PORT as described here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts

Finaly, you could build a script that kill the process using the specific port after the spark-master.sh have run.

Hope it helps a bit.